# Вывод голосующих

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, голоса-против, голоса-за

**Почему** до сих пор, у нас не реализована система вывода тех кто голосует за вопросы/ответы? То есть, грубо говоря, вывод пользователь кто так или иначе проголосовал за ваш вклад в сообщество(вопрос/ответ).

Дело в том что, последнее время я (вероятно это моя паранойя) замечаю как люди, которые не обрели достаточного опыта в нашем сообществе подвергаются тенденции комментариев/голосов. Было бы интересно видеть таких людей, (*а может у нас есть тайные ненавистники?*), чтобы знать кто-что и когда. Было бы интересно видеть и тех кто наоборот, голосует **ЗА**, например находить единомышленников к своим вопросам.

Эти моменты в общем-то и не особо важны, главный вопрос **почему нет?**

Первое что приходит в голову, проблема реализации, если например за вас проголосовало три с половиной человека, то вывод этих людей при наведении, не проблема. Но если случиться что-то что свойственно зарубежному `SO`, и за ваш вопрос например, проголосуют 400 человек, вывод списком при наведении, будет  неприемлемым, но это проблема в принципе решается кнопочкой `learm more` или `Смотреть все` или что либо еще, что будет вести нас на отдельную страницу, где в двух списках будут выводится проголосовавшие за ваш вклад, в первом например те кто нажали на стрелочку вверх а во втором (*очень плохие люди*(нет конечно)) те кто проголосовали против.

Вторая проблема это

> Я аноним, зачем людям видеть что я голосовал против/за, захочу - сам напишу.

И в принципе, да, так и есть и скорее всего, это главный момент из-за которого вывод голосующих не будет принят. Что думаете?

Comment: Со второй проблемой непонятно. Вы хотите видеть кто голосовал за ваши ответы, но не хотите, чтобы видели ваши голоса?

Comment: Все, кто "подвергается тенденции комментариев и голосов" набрали достаточно опыта для этого - у нас есть порог репутации для этого.

Comment: @vp_arth, нет, сам я такой проблеме не подвержен, я так просто обрисовал причину, по которой пользователи могу быть недовольны добавлением голосующих. По поводу порога, знаем, да, но как по мне он слишком мал, чтобы в сто процентов знать что человек голосует "по своей воле".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Потому, что SO - это Q&A-сервис, а не социальная сеть. Плюсы и минусы здесь ставятся контенту, а не генерирующим его пользователям. Если информация о голосах станет публичной, неизбежно возникнет эмоциональная реакция. Даже у самых адекватных пользователей возникнет предубеждённость при оценке вопросов и ответов. А большинство и вовсе начнут "кармические войны", массово минусуя "врагов" и устраивая групповые откачки заминусованной репутации "единомышленников".

Что касается "тайных ненавистников", на сколько мне известно, система ищет подобные закономерности и откатывает систематические минусы. Правда, мне не совсем понятно, как она должна реагировать на мои систематические минусы систематически плохим вопросам/ответам *в корне порочного* пользователя.

Comment: Система только откатывает минусы, но именно из-за шанса ложных срабатываний никак не наказывает.